# Registering key states enough time to be processed SDL

Tags: c++, sdl

I am running a cycle loop using SDL to get the key press. I want for the user to be able to use a key and the game cycle to react to the key press, however I don't know how to go about setting the key to false after cycle is complete without restricting multiple keys beign press or keeping a key pressed.

Currently my problem is that the action gets registered but since there's a while on the event it gets canceled before it gets a chance to be used in the cycle.

Here's my game loop :

```
while(!quit)
    {
        //clock_t t = clock();
        chip.emulateCycle();
        //clock_t end = clock();
        //cout << "Exec time: " << (double(end - t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

        // If the draw flag is set, update the screen
        if(chip.drawFlag) {
            drawGraphics(chip.gfx);
            chip.drawFlag = false;
        }

        while(SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0){
            if(e.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                break;
            }
            else if(e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN){
                switch(e.key.keysym.sym)
                {
                    case SDLK_1: chip.setKey(0x1, 1);break;
                    case SDLK_2: chip.setKey(0x2, 1);break;
                    case SDLK_3: chip.setKey(0x3, 1);break;
                    case SDLK_4: chip.setKey(0xC, 1);break;

                    case SDLK_q: chip.setKey(0x4, 1);break;
                    case SDLK_w: chip.setKey(0x5, 1);break;
                    case SDLK_e: chip.setKey(0x6, 1);break;
                    case SDLK_r: chip.setKey(0xD, 1);break;

                    case SDLK_a: chip.setKey(0x7, 1);break;
                    case SDLK_s: chip.setKey(0x8, 1);break;
                    case SDLK_d: chip.setKey(0x9, 1);break;
                    case SDLK_f: chip.setKey(0xE, 1);break;

                    case SDLK_z: chip.setKey(0xA, 1);break;
                    case SDLK_x: chip.setKey(0x0, 1);break;
                    case SDLK_c: chip.setKey(0xB, 1);break;
                    case SDLK_v: chip.setKey(0xF, 1);break;

                    case SDL_QUIT: quit=true;break;

                }
                break;
            }
            else if(e.type == SDL_KEYUP){
                switch(e.key.keysym.sym)
                {
                    case SDLK_1: chip.setKey(0x1, 0);break;
                    case SDLK_2: chip.setKey(0x2, 0);break;
                    case SDLK_3: chip.setKey(0x3, 0);break;
                    case SDLK_4: chip.setKey(0xC, 0);break;

                    case SDLK_q: chip.setKey(0x4, 0);break;
                    case SDLK_w: chip.setKey(0x5, 0);break;
                    case SDLK_e: chip.setKey(0x6, 0);break;
                    case SDLK_r: chip.setKey(0xD, 0);break;

                    case SDLK_a: chip.setKey(0x7, 0);break;
                    case SDLK_s: chip.setKey(0x8, 0);break;
                    case SDLK_d: chip.setKey(0x9, 0);break;
                    case SDLK_f: chip.setKey(0xE, 0);break;

                    case SDLK_z: chip.setKey(0xA, 0);break;
                    case SDLK_x: chip.setKey(0x0, 0);break;
                    case SDLK_c: chip.setKey(0xB, 0);break;
                    case SDLK_v: chip.setKey(0xF, 0);break;

                }
            }
        }
```

Here's the setKey method:

```
void Base8Chip::setKey(const unsigned char addr, const char state) {
    key[addr] = state;
}
```

here's the key array:

```
unsigned char key[16];
```

Comment: Can you explain further? I see no reason for key state to be reset as key-up fires upon releasing key (or automatically for repeated keypresses, but immediately followed by key-down). You can ignore repeated events but that scenario seems very unlikely. There is also `SDL_GetKeyboardState` function that internally does pretty much the same thing you did, but operates upon scancodes rather than keysyms (you still need to at least read events from queue, but may ignore them).

Comment: In the current setup when I read for events the keydown occurs but because I am using a while to get all the queued events I  end up executing key down to before I run the interpreter cycle so it basically sets the key to 1 and then to 0. I tried putting a break when it gets a key down so it can get executed but on games like pong I need to be able to get multiple key down presses. Basically I need a way to get the state of a specific key at the moment of the request instead of iterating over queued events, is there a way to to do this with SDL_Event or any other SDL system?

Comment: I don't get it at all. If you press and hold key, there is only `SDL_KEYDOWN`, so value remains 1. Even if keypresses are repeated by OS, you'll get keyup and keydown again, so by the end of event queue you still have 1. If that is not the case for you, I suggest making minimal verifyable example, as well as specifying your setup (OS, SDL version, compiler, ...).